# How do I take the end value of a column, convert to date and insert into a new column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column `[week]` in a table `[wkd]` with a value of `11/08 - 11/14`. They are strings with 2 date ranges. (nov 8 - nov 14).

What I need to do is get `11/14` into a new date column `[weekending]` so that it shows `11/14/2015`

How do I go about doing so?

Working code:

```
REPLACE(CAST('2015-' + SUBSTRING([weekrange], charindex('', [weekrange])+9, 10) as varchar(20)),N'/', N'-') as weekending
```

Comment: In general you should submit a self answer instead of putting an answer in your question. Since this is such a short answer that was clearly derived from the accepted answer, you should submit it as a comment on that answer.

Answer (score 2):

Converting strings to date without specifying a format can be a bit tricky, especially when dealing with culture specific constraints.

Please read [Aaron Bertrand's great bad habits to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

You really need to be either storing that stuff as a date, specify a format or use a string that always works.

Comment: i went with varchar for the time being. the table column is a varchar for both weekrange and weekending. i dont think i can convert weekrange to date but im working on weekending. i just posted the code that worked

Comment: @MikeH Did you consider using `WeekStart` and `WeekEnd` (both as `DATE` types) instead of `WeekRange` and `WeekEnding`? That would give you everything you have now and more. Your life would be easier, your queries are likely to be faster, and the developer that inherits the project will won't have to deal with this anti-pattern.

Comment: funny thing is, i am the dev thats inheriting all of this. i was hired for ios programming but i have to do some sql stuff once in a while. the guy i work under mostly handles the sql stuff but hes out of town

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select  
  [weekending] = CAST(SUBSTRING([week], charindex('-', [week])+1, 10) + ', 2015' as date) 
from [wkd]
```

Comment: thanks, i sort of screwed up. you answered the question correctly, but i need the output as 2015-11-14